# Not GUI, only terminal after Ubuntu upgrade (apt-get corrupted)

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, gui

I've recently updated Ubuntu to 18.04 but after reset, I can't see nothing except terminal.

So I've tried to install `ubuntu-desktop` but it just showed errors. Then I tried couple of steps but nothing works. I can't copy paste the terminal so I'm adding the photo. [image]

Apparently, there is a problem with `apt-get`. So the first thing I try `-f install`

[image]

It looks like that the upgrade wasn't completed so some libraries are newer and some older. As you can see many libraries has older dependencies than installed.

I tried everything I could. I can't even update or purge those libs.

So I try to purge the first lib `debconf-i18n`:

[image]

Do you have any ideas how to make it work again?

Comment: sudo apt install aptitude && sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop

Answer (score 0):

Your APT package system is broken. This can be difficult to fix.

Perform a fresh install using an installation USB or DVD. If you want to keep your data and configuration, then in the installer, select "Something else". Assign the partitions as they were in previous install, and *uncheck* the format checkbox. This way, system files will be reinstalled, and your configuration and user files will be preserved.

Still, you always should ensure your backup is up to date before engaging in a system install.

Comment: Yes I was afraid that it's the only way. Do you think it's ok to install 19.04/10 this way? Or should it be 18.04? Thanks